# How to use Maven assembly with accent in directory name on Jenkins Docker?

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin

I use `maven-assembly-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

assembly file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>rules</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <baseDirectory>xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules</baseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>target</exclude>
            </excludes>         
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I have at `root` directory a folder named `règle`. I use `mvn clean deploy`. On my Windows 10 device, I have restult OK with `règle` folder in my jar file final but if I build on my Jenkins Unix Docker, I have a success build but without my folder named `règle` in my jar file final.

**EDIT** logs in Jenkins Docker:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**EDIT 2** (add -X on Maven command):

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) appendAssemblyId = true
[DEBUG]   (f) attach = true
[DEBUG]   (s) basedir = /home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_Common_xxxGenerate/xxx-xxx-xxxframework/xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-xxx
[DEBUG]   (s) descriptor = assembly.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) dryRun = false
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = Cp1252
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG] All known ContainerDescriptorHandler components: [file-aggregator, metaInf-spring, plexus, metaInf-services]
[DEBUG] FileSet[] dir perms: -1 file perms: -1
[DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
[DEBUG] NOT reformatting any files in /home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_Common_xxxGenerate/xxx-xxx-xxxframework/xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/.
[DEBUG] Adding file-set in: /home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_Common_xxxGenerate/xxx-xxx-xxxframework/xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/. to archive location: xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/
[DEBUG] adding directory xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/
[DEBUG] adding directory xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/.settings/
[DEBUG] adding directory xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/bom/
[DEBUG] adding directory xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/ressources/
[DEBUG] adding directory xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/ressources/xom-libraries/
[DEBUG] adding directory xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/target/
[DEBUG] adding directory xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/target/archive-tmp/
```

**EDIT 4:**

I try add this but do not work:

```
<fileMode>0755</fileMode>
<directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
```

**EDIT 5:**

I add this:

```
withMaven(globalMavenSettingsConfig: 'empty-global-settings', mavenSettingsConfig: Constants.CONFIG_SETTINGS_ID) {
    sh "pwd"
    sh "ls -lrt"
    sh "ls -lrt /home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_Common_xxxGenerate/xxx-xxx-commonutility/xxx-xxx-CommonUtility-rules"
    sh "ls -lrt /home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_Common_xxxGenerate/xxx-xxx-commonutility/xxx-xxx-CommonUtility-rules/règles"
    sh "$MVN_CMD deploy -X"
}
```

and my result is:

```
+ ls -lrt /home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_Common_xxxGenerate/xxx-xxx-commonutility/xxx-xxx-CommonUtility-rules
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 jenkins root  125 Jul 15 21:32 bom
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins root  657 Jul 15 21:32 assembly.xml
drwxr-xr-x. 3 jenkins root   27 Jul 15 21:32 ressources
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins root 1492 Jul 15 21:32 pom.xml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 jenkins root   57 Jul 15 21:32 data
drwxr-xr-x. 3 jenkins root   23 Jul 15 21:32 règles
drwxr-xr-x. 3 jenkins root   82 Jul 15 21:32 target
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -lrt $'/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx_Common_xxxGenerate/xxx-xxx-commonutility/xxx-xxx-CommonUtility-rules/r\303\250gles'
total 0
```

Comment: Does it work if the folder is called "regle", without the accent? A lot of software doesn't handle non-english characters well.

Comment: @Erlkoenig, it works locally (Windows 10) when it does not work on my Jenkins which uses Docker on unix. `règle` is mandatory. I do not looking for a workarround without accent.

Comment: Can you test it without the accent on Unix (what kind of Unix)? Just to find out whether that is the cause of the problem. If it isn't the cause, you don't need a workaround for that.

Comment: @Erlkoenig, if we remove the accent, the Maven assembly works but it is my application that does not work. I need this accent, hence my question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay, so the accent _is_ the problem. Using Cp1252 or ISO-8859-15 on Unix is unusual, what happens if you encode the file name (with accent) as UTF-8?

Comment: `règle` is a folder, is not a file.

Comment: So? The folder _name_ `règle` has an encoding too, and the question title says it's supposedly ISO-8859-15. Unix (Linux) usually uses UTF-8, so that might work better.

Comment: how do i change the encoding of the directory? I'm using Git.

Comment: You could try `git mv règle r\`printf "\303\250"\`gle` on a Linux system to rename the file into an UTF-8 encoded filename. After typing the first `r`, press `<TAB>` to autocomplete the filename on the command line into whatever encoding it currently is. In `git status`, the filename should then appear as `r\303\250gle`, indicating the Non-ASCII characters.

Comment: `$ git mv règle r\`printf "\303\250"\`gle`
fatal: can not move directory into itself, source=xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/r+¿gles, destination=xxx-xxx-xxxFramework-rules/r+¿gles/r+¿gles

Comment: Then the directory name is already UTF-8 and your question title is wrong.

Comment: OK, So I edit the title

Comment: Why does it say `encoding = Cp1252`? Looks like you need to set that to UTF-8.

Comment: I see `encoding = Cp1252` but where configure (how to) to UTF-8 ?

Comment: Perhaps [like this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html)?

Comment: I found how to set the encoding to UTF-8 but I still have the problem

Comment: Then I don't know.

Comment: Why does your Docker container have this strange platform encoding: `platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968`  ?

Comment: @JFMeier, find the problem, I change my Docker image and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I convert my comment to an answer:

The problem seems to be the strange encoding of the Docker image:

```
platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
```